# Vite versions higher than 2.9.14 will not build my project

Tags: vite

I have a Vite React project that I've been working on for a while now. Previously I've been on vite 2.9.14 and @vitejs/plugin-react version 1.3.2. I decided it was a good time to upgrade to the latest versions of both.

The result of doing so is my production build (vite build) doesn't compile my TypeScript/React and SCSS code. It has my index.html, it has my publicDir resources, but then the only asset it produces is a single JS file with a tiny amount of what appears to just be setup code. None of my application code is included.

I'll add that the dev server (vite) works perfectly.

I'm trying to go to vite 4.0.4 and @vitejs/plugin-react 3.0.1. I've scoured the internet trying to understand what could be going wrong here. I can't even find any reported issues like mine.

I am staying on the older versions for now.

```
import path from 'path';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import fs from 'fs';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

const https =
    process.env.CYPRESS === 'true'
        ? undefined
        : {
                cert: fs.readFileSync(
                    path.join(
                        process.cwd(),
                        'dev',
                        'certs',
                        'localhost.cert.pem'
                    ),
                    'utf8'
                ),
                key: fs.readFileSync(
                    path.join(
                        process.cwd(),
                        'dev',
                        'certs',
                        'localhost.key.pem'
                    ),
                    'utf8'
                )
          };

export default defineConfig({
    root: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src'),
    base: '/expense-tracker/',
    publicDir: path.join(process.cwd(), 'public'),
    envDir: path.join(process.cwd(), 'environment'),
    server: {
        port: 3002,
        host: true,
        https,
        proxy: {
            '/expense-tracker/api': {
                target: 'https://localhost:8080',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false,
                rewrite: (path: string) =>
                    path.replace(/^\/expense-tracker\/api/, '')
            },
            '/expense-tracker/oauth2': {
                target: 'https://apps-craigmiller160.ddns.net/oauth2',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false,
                rewrite: (path: string) =>
                    path.replace(/^\/expense-tracker\/oauth2/, '')
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [react()],
    build: {
        target: 'esnext',
        outDir: path.join(process.cwd(), 'build'),
        emptyOutDir: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem. My index.html was importing my root typescript file incorrectly. In previous vite versions, the following relative path syntax was supported:

```
<script type="module" src="./index.tsx"></script>
```

Now, it has to be written with an absolute path like this:

```
<script type="module" src="/index.tsx"></script>
```

Now everything works perfectly.